# Python selenium - I'm trying to interact with a new window and receving a StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a script that interacts with the website Autotask.net. I'm at the point where it'll open a new window. I've attempted to switch frames and switch windows with my limited knowledge, but I've received the exception below:

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it

Here's my code:

```
# Below code WORKS as is.
browser.switch_to_frame('PageContainerFrame')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(., "T20160101.0100")]').click()

#TESTING

browser.switch_to_default_content()
browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
title=browser.title
newNote=browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#btnNewNote')
actions.click(newNote)
actions.perform()
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toolbar" id="Toolbar" style=
    "margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:0px;">
        <input class="BlueberryImageButton" id="btnNewTicket" name=
        "btnNewTicket" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { if (window.opener &amp;&amp; window.opener.TicketNew) {window.opener.TicketNew();} else { javascript: if(!PageIsLoading){if(typeof(e) == 'undefined'){e = null;} var eventEx = e || window.event;if(eventEx){eventEx = new Sys.UI.DomEvent(eventEx);} if(eventEx!=null &amp;&amp; eventEx.target!=null &amp;&amp; (eventEx.target.tagName=='A' || eventEx.target.tagName=='a')){}else{var a='/autotask/views/ServiceDesk/ServiceDeskTicket/service_ticket_new.aspx';var oWin=window.open(a,'TicketNew131218942347837951','height=690,width=940,top=0,left=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0',true);if(oWin &amp;&amp; !oWin.closed){oWin.focus();}}} } };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/ticket.png?v=24241" title=
        "New Ticket" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" disabled=
        "disabled" id="btnNewTicketDisabled" name="btnNewTicketDisabled"
        onclick="return false;" src=
        "/autotask/images/icons/NewTicket_disabled.png?v=24241" style=
        "cursor: default; display: none;" title="New Ticket" type=
        "image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id="btnNewTimeEntry" name=
        "btnNewTimeEntry" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.timeEntry.open('', '', event); return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/time.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Time Entry" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton"
        disabled="disabled" id="btnNewTimeEntryDisabled" name=
        "btnNewTimeEntryDisabled" onclick="return false;" src=
        "/autotask/graphics/icons/content/time-disabled.png?v=24241" style=
        "cursor: default; display: none;" title=
        "You cannot enter time on a ticket with a status of Complete." type=
        "image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id="btnNewNote" name=
        "btnNewNote" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.note.open('', '', event); return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/note.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Note" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnNewAttachment" name="btnNewAttachment" onclick=
        "window.open('/Mvc/File/Upload.mvc/TicketAttachment?enablePublishing=true&amp;ticketId=107599','TicketAttachment','height=376,width=895,top=0,left=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0');return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/attachment.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Attachment" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnNewCost" name="btnNewCost" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.cost.open('', '', event); return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/costs.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Charge" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnNewExpense" name="btnNewExpense" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.expense.open('', '', event); return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/coin_gold.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Expense" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnNewServiceCall" name="btnNewServiceCall" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.serviceCall.open(null, '&amp;action=3');return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/service-calls.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add Service Call" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnNewToDo" name="btnNewToDo" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.toDo.open(null, '&amp;fromPage=Ticket');return false; };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/todos.png?v=24241" title=
        "Add To-Do" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnPrintTicket" name="btnPrintTicket" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { javascript: if(!PageIsLoading){if(typeof(e) == 'undefined'){e = null;} var eventEx = e || window.event;if(eventEx){eventEx = new Sys.UI.DomEvent(eventEx);} if(eventEx!=null &amp;&amp; eventEx.target!=null &amp;&amp; (eventEx.target.tagName=='A' || eventEx.target.tagName=='a')){}else{var a='/autotask/views/servicedesk/servicedeskTicket/service_ticket_printer_friendly_view.aspx?ticketId='+serviceTicket.get_ticketId()+'';var oWin=window.open(a,'PrintFriendlyView','height=750,width=920,top=0,left=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0',true);if(oWin &amp;&amp; !oWin.closed){oWin.focus();}}} };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/print-view.png?v=24241" title=
        "Print View" type="image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id=
        "btnAcceptTicket" name="btnAcceptTicket" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { serviceTicket.acceptTicket(); };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/accept-ticket.png?v=24241" style=
        "display: none;" title="Accept Ticket" type="image"><input class=
        "BlueberryImageButton" id="btnAcceptTicketDisabled" name=
        "btnAcceptTicketDisabled" onclick="return false;" src=
        "/autotask/graphics/icons/content/accept-ticket-disabled.png?v=24241"
        style="cursor: default;" title="Accept Ticket" type=
        "image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id="btnForwardTicket" name=
        "btnForwardTicket" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { javascript: if(!PageIsLoading){if(typeof(e) == 'undefined'){e = null;} var eventEx = e || window.event;if(eventEx){eventEx = new Sys.UI.DomEvent(eventEx);} if(eventEx!=null &amp;&amp; eventEx.target!=null &amp;&amp; (eventEx.target.tagName=='A' || eventEx.target.tagName=='a')){}else{var a='/ServiceDesk/Popups/Forward/svcForward.asp?forward=1&amp;taskIds='+serviceTicket.get_ticketId()+'';var oWin=window.open(a,'ForwardTicket','height=720,width=650,top=0,left=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=0,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0',true);if(oWin &amp;&amp; !oWin.closed){oWin.focus();}}} };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/forward.png?v=24241" title=
        "Forward/Modify Ticket" type="image"><input class=
        "BlueberryImageButton" id="btnCompleteTicket" name="btnCompleteTicket"
        onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.completeTicket.open(); };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/checkbox-complete.png?v=24241"
        title="Complete Ticket" type="image"><input class=
        "BlueberryImageButton" disabled="disabled" id=
        "btnCompleteTicketDisabled" name="btnCompleteTicketDisabled" onclick=
        "return false;" src=
        "/autotask/graphics/icons/content/checkbox-complete-disabled.png?v=24241"
        style="cursor: default; display: none;" title="Complete Ticket" type=
        "image"><input class="BlueberryImageButton" id="btnToGoReport" name=
        "btnToGoReport" onclick=
        "if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { javascript: if(!PageIsLoading){if(typeof(e) == 'undefined'){e = null;} var eventEx = e || window.event;if(eventEx){eventEx = new Sys.UI.DomEvent(eventEx);} if(eventEx!=null &amp;&amp; eventEx.target!=null &amp;&amp; (eventEx.target.tagName=='A' || eventEx.target.tagName=='a')){}else{var a='/servicedesk/reports/toGoReportFrame.asp?taskObjectId='+serviceTicket.get_ticketId()+'';var oWin=window.open(a,'ToGoReport','height=600,width=800,top=0,left=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0',true);if(oWin &amp;&amp; !oWin.closed){oWin.focus();}}} };return false;"
        src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/report.png?v=24241" title=
        "To Go Report" type="image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<input name="btnNewNote" id="btnNewNote" title="Add Note" class="BlueberryImageButton" src="/autotask/graphics/icons/content/note.png?v=24241" onclick="if (serviceTicket.get_bodyLoaded() === true) { popupBroker.note.open('', '', event); return false; };return false;" language="javascript" border="0" type="image">
```

Comment: unless we have HTML, we can't really help you with this.  please share the HTML that surrounds the element (you can of course truncate.)  but we need to see the Frame(s) that surround this element in order to help

Comment: two things:  1) that's not all i asked - we need *surrounding* html.  2) please edit your question to include the source. do not comment with source

Comment: I know. I'm making sure I'm using the proper formatting before posting it.

Comment: I hope I posted it correctly. Let me know if you need more information. It's a lot of html.